# sbt test encoding issue

Tags: scala, utf-8

I have a very similar issue as [sbt test encoding hickup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712216/sbt-test-encoding-hickup) but since the answer does not apply and my case is in Scala code I ask here.

I have a string containing non ASCII characters in a unit test. This test is working fine on Linux, and fine on Windows when run from IntelliJ. However, when run from a Windows shell with `sbt test` they fail. If I print the string `humanité` it is displayed as `humanitΘ` in the failing case. The file encoding is UTF-8.

`println(new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in).getEncoding)` returns `UTF8` when run from IntelliJ, and `Cp1252` from the shell. I tried various things to change the encoding:

- run `sbt "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" test`
- check that scalacOptions defined in my build.sbt contains "-encoding", "UTF8"

But the default encoding is always `Cp1252` (maybe that's normal?) and the test keeps failing.

The failing code is the following:

```
val stringToEncrypt = "l'humanité"
println(test)
```

From IntelliJ I get:

```
l'humanité
```

From a windows shell running sbt:

```
l'humanitΘ
```

Comment: Are you using Source.fromInputStream?

Comment: I am using it somewhere in my project, but not in the path tested I think.

Comment: You need to explicitely set the encoding when consuming the stream,suc

Comment: My issue is not in a flow using this method unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid problems with default charset for OS, you can pass explicitly the desired charset when creating the `InputStream`:

```
new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in,"UTF-8")
```

Comment: The code with InputStreamReader was just here to point out my encoding issue. The root issue is that it looks like sbt when run from the shell does not pick the right encoding when compiling my scala source code.

Comment: We found that to avoid this case, the best thing is to pass the encoding explicitly: we had this problem when running the tests with docker

Comment: not sure what you mean then, how do you specify the encoding of a String you create?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[],%20java.nio.charset.Charset)

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean, I will enhance the question to make it more clear.